# Get the type of interface's value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following interface available:

```
export interface SchemaAttributes {
  [key: string]: (
    SchemaAttributeDefinition<NumberConstructor, number>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<[NumberConstructor], number[]>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<DateConstructor, Date>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<StringConstructor, string>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<[StringConstructor], string[]>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<ObjectConstructor, Object>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<ArrayConstructor, Array<any>>
    | SchemaAttributeDefinition<any, any>
    | RawSchemaAttributeDefinition<any, any>
    | NumberConstructor
    | [NumberConstructor]
    | DateConstructor
    | StringConstructor
    | [StringConstructor]
    | ObjectConstructor
    | ArrayConstructor
  )
}
```

How can I access the combined type that is assigned to the `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index type query for this:

```
type Foo = SchemaAttributes['string'];
```

[More on index types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)